# How to set picked contact in listview?

Tags: android, listview

hi all I want to set the picked contact in a `Listview`
**Here is my code:**

```
  TextView contactsDisplay;
    Button pickContacts,Btn_sms,Btn_call;
    final int CONTACT_PICK_REQUEST = 1000;
ListView lst;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Btn_sms=(Button) findViewById(R.id.for_sms);
Btn_call=(Button)findViewById(R.id.for_call);
        contactsDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_selected_contacts);
        pickContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pick_contacts);
lst =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        pickContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intentContactPick = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactsPickerActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intentContactPick,CONTACT_PICK_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICK_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            ArrayList<Contact> selectedContacts = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("SelectedContacts");

            String display="";
            for(int i=0;i<selectedContacts.size();i++){

                display += (i+1)+". "+selectedContacts.get(i).toString()+"\n";

            }
            contactsDisplay.setText("Selected Contacts : \n\n"+display);
        }
    }
```

I did that with a `TextView`(ContactsDisplay), but now I want to do  with ListView(lst)

Do anyone have some solutions about this issue

Comment: what do you want to to with ListView after receive picked contact?

Comment: i want to save them in listview so that i can use them in my app after

Answer (score 0):

Please look following solution.

```
package com.chayanchowdhurycontact;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.chayanchowdhurycontact.adapter.SelectUserAdapter;
import com.chayanchowdhurycontact.getset.SelectUser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// ArrayList
ArrayList<SelectUser> selectUsers;
List<SelectUser> temp;
// Contact List
ListView listView;
// Cursor to load contacts list
Cursor phones, email;

// Pop up
ContentResolver resolver;
SearchView search;
SelectUserAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

    phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
    loadContact.execute();

    search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    //*** setOnQueryTextListener ***
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

// Load data on background
class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Get Contact list from Phone

        if (phones != null) {
            Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
            if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No contacts in your contact list.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                Bitmap bit_thumb = null;
                String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String EmailAddr = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA2));
                String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
                try {
                    if (image_thumb != null) {
                        bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                    } else {
                        Log.e("No Image Thumb", "--------------");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                selectUser.setName(name);
                selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                selectUser.setEmail(id);
                selectUser.setCheckedBox(false);
                selectUsers.add(selectUser);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
        }
        //phones.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Select item on listclick
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");

                SelectUser data = selectUsers.get(i);
            }
        });

        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    phones.close();
}
```

}

```
adapter class:--

public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public List<SelectUser> _data;
private ArrayList<SelectUser> arraylist;
Context _c;
ViewHolder v;
RoundImage roundedImage;

public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
    _data = selectUsers;
    _c = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return _data.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_info, null);
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
    }

    v = new ViewHolder();

    v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
    v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
    v.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    final SelectUser data = (SelectUser) _data.get(i);
    v.title.setText(data.getName());
    v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
    v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

    // Set image if exists
    try {

        if (data.getThumb() != null) {
            v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
        } else {
            v.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        }
        // Seting round image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(view.getResources(), R.drawable.image); // Load default image
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        v.imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // Add default picture
        v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this._c.getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + data.getThumb());

    /*// Set check box listener android
    v.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                data.setCheckedBox(true);
              } else {
                data.setCheckedBox(false);
            }
        }
    });*/

    view.setTag(data);
    return view;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _data.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _data.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _data.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title, phone;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

}

```
Model class:--
public class SelectUser {
String name;

public Bitmap getThumb() {
    return thumb;
}

public void setThumb(Bitmap thumb) {
    this.thumb = thumb;
}

Bitmap thumb;

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

String phone;

public Boolean getCheckedBox() {
    return checkedBox;
}

public void setCheckedBox(Boolean checkedBox) {
    this.checkedBox = checkedBox;
}

Boolean checkedBox = false;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}